# Intuitive description of spectrum of Brownian random walk motion

Tags: mathematical-statistics, spectral-analysis, brownian-motion

I found the description that Brownian random walk has the power spectrum on the dependency of $\dfrac{1}{f^{2}}$ where $f$ is its time frequency.

I wonder why it is but couldn't find the proof there and also in some pages I googled.

The question is why Brownian random walk has the power spectrum that depends on  the inverse of the square of its frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Brownian noise produced by the Brownian random walk is the integral of the white noise, whose PSD is flat. The proof is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_noise).

Comment: The proof is cool! I didn't expect there is such good proof in Wikipedia :)